# How to find the first occurance of NAs based on the levels of a specific column

Tags: r, dplyr, statistics, missing-data

I have these data:

```
X1<-c(1.1,0.2,0.4,0.8,1.3,2.3,1.1,3.2,NA,0.8,2.1,NA,1.1,0.2,0.4,0.8,NA,0.6)
X2<-c(0.8,NA,1.2,0.3,NA,NA,0.8,NA,1.5,2.7,2.2,NA,0.8,3.1,1.7,0.3,1.1,2.4)
Time<-c("baseline","week1","week2","week3","week4","week5","baseline","week1","week2","week3","week4","week5","baseline","week1","week2","week3","week4","week5")
data<-data.frame(X1,X2,Time)
```

I want to find out at which time point the first NA occurred in X1 and X2

I did this but it doesn't give the correct output that I want:

```
data %>%
group_by (Time)
filter (is.na(X1)) %>%
slice (1) %>%
ungroup ()
```

what I want for X1 for instance, is an output like this:

```
Time    
Week 2
```

Can anyone give a hand?

Comment: what is wrong with your code?

Comment: @onyambu when I try it on my actual data, it gives me a list of NA in front of each of my time points

Comment: But that is what you need. they are NA. so they will give you NA for X1. X2 might not be NA

Comment: @onyambu Not really, for one of my variables, the first occurrence of NA is on Week1 and not the baseline but what I get is NA is front of each level of my Time variable. I believe what this code does is find out of there is any NA at each level of Time and if there is, it will show it in the output but that is not what I want. For instance, I only wanted it to show me Week1 for that specific variable

Comment: Could you include the full output you expect? Probably you need to remove the `group_by` part

Comment: @onyambu Thank you, so as I mentioned at the end of my question, the full output for variable X1 should be only Week2 because the first NA for this variable happened when Time=Week2

Comment: `data %>% filter(is.na(X1))%>%slice_head(n = 1)%>%select(Time)`

Comment: The code is just exactly what you have apart from the group. DO not group

Comment: @onyambu can I find how many times for instance Week2 happened other than the first occurrence? (In the same line of code I mean, although I think that is not possible since I`m only coding for the first occurrence?)

Comment: You could find the total number of week 2 NA instances, and subtract 1 if NA first occurrence was week2

Comment: @onyambu not sure how to do that exactly, remove the slice_head part?

Comment: first do the count ie `data %>% filter(is.na(X1))%>%group_by(Time)%>%count()` or even `data %>% filter(is.na(X1))%>%select(Time)%>%table()` then select the week2 value and subtract 1

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
temp <- data %>% apply(2, function(x) which(is.na(x))[1])
data$Time[temp]
```

Comment: Thank you but on my real data, this code gives me a list of all variables with some numbers beneath each of them. It doesn`t tell me at which timepoint the first NA happened for my desire variable

Comment: The number is the index of the first NA. So all you have to do is index your time variable with those numbers. I edited my answer to show how to do it.

Comment: Many thanks, just one question, how can I identify which variable I want to find the NAs in? I`m not very familiar with this code but the last line you added now give me NA and other levels of my Time variable. The only thing that is missing is that I`m not sure for which variable it shows these info